# Decimal serialization JSON to Web API

Tags: json, angularjs, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have problem getting json data containing even float: 10.0.

AngularJS

```
        var replenishAccount = { ReloadThresholdAmount: parseFloat(vm.account.ReloadThresholdAmount), ReloadAmount: parseFloat(vm.account.ReloadAmount) };

        var webApiUrl = "https://localhost:44301";
        $http({ method: 'PATCH', url: webApiUrl + '/api/account/patch/' + vm.account.ID, data: angular.toJson(replenishAccount)})
```

JSON

```
{"ReloadThresholdAmount": 10.2, "ReloadAmount": 10}
```

What I need is

```
{"ReloadThresholdAmount": 10.2, "ReloadAmount": 10.0}
```

If I do .toFix(2), I get the string but web api expects decimal.

```
{"ReloadThresholdAmount": "10.2", "ReloadAmount": "10.0"}
```

Basically, Web Api complains that it cannot be string or integer.

Web API, I am using Delta. Those 2 amounts are double in .NET.

```
        [Route("Patch/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Patch(int id, Delta<Account> account)
    {
        if (account == null)
            return BadRequest();

            Account accountFromDb = Account.GetInstanceByID(CurrentUser, id);
            account.Patch(accountFromDb);
            accountFromDb.Save(CurrentUser);

            return Ok(account);

    }
```

Comment: Why do you need that `10.0` notation? Generally speaking JavaScript engines regard 10.0 as equal to 10, and strip that "unneeded decimal" away eg. in JSON.stringify() and in JSON.parse(). IMHO you should fix this problem on the backend side, so that it would regard 10 as the same as 10.0.

Comment: You should post the Web API method

Comment: Posted the web api with the delta. Property remains 0 if 10 (10.0 got truncated from js) but correct if 10.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is specific to deserializing Delta object. Delta is meant to used with [ODataMediaTypeFormatter](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/easy-asp-net-web-api-resource-updates-with-delta/) and using it with JSON.NET (NewtonSoft) is buggy with integer etc. Many SO posts supported this argument.

I finally used [Asp.net Delta Json Deserialization](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/DeltaJsonDeserialization/ReadMe.txt) and added this to web config. This serializes Delta in a breeze, after hours of debugging and researching.

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET, which is the out of the box deserializer for Web API correctly deserialize the `{"ReloadThresholdAmount": 10.2, "ReloadAmount": 10}` JSON into decimals.

e.g. your class should be

```
public class ReplenishAccount
{
    public decimal ReloadThresholdAmount;
    public decimal ReloadAmount;
}
```

Then

```
var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReplenishAccount>(json);        
Console.WriteLine("ReloadThresholdAmount: {0:0.0}; ReloadAmount: {1:0.0}", account.ReloadThresholdAmount, account.ReloadAmount);
```

works as expected (fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YX5FsR).

In Web API, you would use `[FromBody]` attribute, and it should deserialize the same exact way.